# Removing HTML Tag removes additional words

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, tags, python-re

I am working on a data cleaning problem wherein I have a task to remove HTML tags from string while keeping the content of text.

Example text for cleanup is given below. I tried removing "pre" tags and somehow i do not get any data.

```
x = '<pre>i am </pre><p>  siddharth </p><pre> sid </pre>'
re.sub(r'<pre>.*<\/pre>', '', x)
```

If I try adding "\n" which i deleted before, i do get output as shown below

```
x = '<pre>i am </pre>\n<p>  siddharth </p><pre> sid </pre>'
re.sub(r'<pre>.*<\/pre>', '', x)
```

output - '\n

siddharth

'

```
A string from dataset for cleanup is given below for reference

'<p>I\'ve written a database generation script in <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL">SQL</a> and want to execute it in my <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Integrated_Runtime">Adobe AIR</a> application: </p> <pre> <code> Create Table tRole (      roleID integer Primary Key      ,roleName varchar(40));Create Table tFile (    fileID integer Primary Key    ,fileName varchar(50)    ,fileDescription varchar(500)    ,thumbnailID integer    ,fileFormatID integer    ,categoryID integer    ,isFavorite boolean    ,dateAdded date    ,globalAccessCount integer    ,lastAccessTime date    ,downloadComplete boolean    ,isNew boolean    ,isSpotlight boolean    ,duration varchar(30));Create Table tCategory (    categoryID integer Primary Key    ,categoryName varchar(50)    ,parent_categoryID integer);... </code> </pre> <p> I execute this in Adobe AIR using the following methods: </p> <pre> <code> public static function RunSqlFromFile(fileName:String):void {    var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(fileName);    var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();    stream.open(file, FileMode.READ)    var strSql:String = stream.readUTFBytes(stream.bytesAvailable);    NonQuery(strSql);}public static function NonQuery(strSQL:String):void{    var sqlConnection:SQLConnection = new SQLConnection();    sqlConnection.open(File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(DBPATH);    var sqlStatement:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();    sqlStatement.text = strSQL;    sqlStatement.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;    try    {        sqlStatement.execute();    }    catch (error:SQLError)    {        Alert.show(error.toString());    }} </code> </pre> <p> No errors are generated, however only <code>tRole</code> exists. It seems that it only looks at the first query (up to the semicolon- if I remove it, the query fails). Is there a way to call multiple queries in one statement?</p>'
```

Detailed code for cleanup is given below. The array "arr" contains all the text for which cleanup is needed.

```
arr = [i.replace('\n','') for i in arr]
arr = [re.sub(r'<pre>.*<\/pre>', '', i) for i in arr]
arr = [re.sub(f'<code>.*<\/code>', '', i) for i in arr]
arr = [re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', i) for i in arr]
```

Kindly let me know if anyone has experienced same issue and is able to surpass this blockage.

Comment: Try non-greedy modifier in the regular expression: `'<pre>.*?<\/pre>'`

Comment: Please fix the formatting. I'm quite sure `A string from dataset for cleanup is given below for reference` is not supposed to be formatted as code -- and looks like there's other comments from you in that huge line that should not be there. Assuming that's not really your dataset...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of `BeautifulSoup` tagging - To remove a specific tag and keep its content may use `.unwrap()`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<pre>i am </pre><p>  siddharth </p><pre> sid </pre>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.select('pre'):
    tag.unwrap()

soup
```

->

```
i am <p>  siddharth </p> sid
```

Or to extract texts only use `.get_text()`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<pre>i am </pre>\n<p>  siddharth </p><pre> sid </pre>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

soup.get_text(' ', strip=True)
```

->

```
i am siddharth sid
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method, using `.extract()`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = '<pre>i am </pre><p>  siddharth </p><pre> sid </pre>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

# remove <pre> and <code> tags:
for tag in soup.select('pre, code'):
    tag.extract()

# get remaining text:
text = soup.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ')
print(text)
```

Prints:

```
siddharth
```